# ORA-07445 access violation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-03113

I have this error when running a large query on oracle. any advice?
I'm using pl sql version 10.2

I have noticed that the error is due to creating a view that is based up on many tables, and when  I do a select from this view to a specific parameter with a where condition I got that error. When I checked the logs I found out this

> ora 07445 access violation

So it is due to something on the view. I have full rights on the tables that I'm creating the views from. And I'm not using any network, the database is on my machine.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using oracle plsql and having the problem on vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the useful `oerr` command:

```
$ oerr ora 3113
03113, 00000, "end-of-file on communication channel"
// *Cause: The connection between Client and Server process was broken.
// *Action: There was a communication error that requires further investigation.
//          First, check for network problems and review the SQL*Net setup.
//          Also, look in the alert.log file for any errors. Finally, test to
//          see whether the server process is dead and whether a trace file
//          was generated at failure time.
```

So the likeliest causes:

1. The server process you were connected to crashed.
2. A network problem broke your connection.
3. Someone manually killed the process on the server you were connected to.

When the server process you were connected to crashed, it threw an ORA-07445.  That error, along with ORA-00600, are relatively famous Oracle errors.  They're functionally unhandled exceptions, with an ORA-00600 being an unhandled exception in the Oracle code, whereas ORA-07445 is a fatal signal from the OS, generally because Oracle did something that the OS didn't approve of, so the OS killed the Oracle process.

Oracle's support site (http://metalink.oracle.com) has an online troubleshooter for these errors -- search within metalink for document 600.1, and enter the appropriate information from the log file and you might receive some useful troubleshooting information.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually when something is killed at the database server OS level.  But it is a fairly generic error.  But in my specific world, I'll see this in an application server log on machine A if the database server on machine B is shutdown.  In your case, your desktop is losing communication with your DBMS.  Your 'large query' may be getting killed at the process level if some administrator or automated process is identifying your query as a resource hog (i.e. you have a Cartesian product).

To be clear this is very likely something your doing wrong as the client and not a bug with your server or Oracle itself.

**UPDATE** since you provided additional details.  Since the db is running on your machine I would bet that your query is encountering a lack of RAM to support both client and server operations.